# Node.js REST endpoint not catching parameters passed from axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, axios

I'm making a POST request from a React front-end using axios to an endpoint to save some data to my DB (MongoDB). I'm getting an error that one **cannot read property 'name' of undefined**. I think that's occurring because req.body is undefined but I can't understand what's wrong with my axios request. I logged all the parameters and they are there (not undefined). The axios request and the endpoint are written below. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**Axios Request**

```
const uploadElement = async (name, HTMLCode, JSCode, CSSCode, screenshot) => {
console.log(name)
  try {

    await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/api/elements',
      data: {
        name: name,
        HTMLCode,
        JSCode,
        CSSCode,
        screenshot
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
  }
}
```

**Endpoint for POST Request**

```
router.post("/", upload.single("screenshot"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newElement = new Element({
      name: req.body.name,
      JSCode: req.body.JSCode,
      HTMLCode: req.body.HTMLCode,
      CSSCode: req.body.CSSCode,
      screenshot: req.file.buffer,
    });

    await newElement.save();
    res.send("Data uploaded successfully!");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require('cors');

const elementRouter = require("./routes/elementRoute");
const authRouter = require("./routes/authRoute");

const connectDB = require("./config/db");

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
connectDB();

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "googleOAuth",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

app.use(cors());

// Passport Config
require("./config/passport")(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/api/elements", elementRouter);
app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Can you show your serverside `index.js` or `server.js`

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer Added to the question.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer It's working for all the text fields but not for the image. Can you tell me how to parse that?

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to do with the file on the backend? and what is the file format on the front end?

Comment: The file is an image of jpeg/png format on the front end. It's actually a screenshot of the component. I know that it's not good practice to save it on the DB but for some reason I have to do it

Comment: Do you convert the file to a string before submitting it?

Comment: No. Should I convert it into a base64 string? Also even if I do it. How will I send it to req.file instead of req.body

Comment: So if you conver it to a base64 string before sending it you can just access it via `req.body.screenshot`, otherwise as far as I know (and I may be wrong on this) you can't submit formdata (files) and regular input data together and you would also need some plugin like `multer` on your backend to get access to the files on your request  (`req.files`) like you needed `body-parser` to access the data, but in your case you can convert the file to a string before submitting it and then saving it to the database as a string.

Comment: I am using multer only to access my file as req.file.screenshot. Yeah I am researching and I can't seem to find how to handle forms with multiple data types. i am thinking of making one more enpoint for the file upload and calling it just after my first POST request to send all the text data

Comment: The way I do it is that I have an endpoint for the upload that stores it on Azure cloud and returns a URL for the file and then when I submit the form I submit the url as the file value. if that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah it does. Anyway thanks a ton for your help! Means a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install and require `body-parser` in your serverside code

First run `npm i --save body-parser`

Then require it like this

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

Then use it after you declare your app ( after this line `const app = express();`)

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This makes the data of your request available in `req.body`